# Can't remove an object from public mutable array (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

This program should theoretically load a random string with image by click. This works OK, but I wanted to add a function that removes a current object from both arrays, so I made all arrays and integer public (right?) and  made mutable copies for the arrays. Then I wrote three lines at the bottom and `Xcode` showed this:

> No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector
>   'removeObjectAtIndex'

What does it mean? How to fix it?

```
  #import "KotikViewController.h"

@interface KotikViewController (){
    NSArray *movieNames;
    NSArray *movieCovers;
    NSArray *movieNamesMutableCopie;
    NSArray *movieCoversMutableCopie;
    NSInteger yourRandomIndex;
}

@end

@implementation KotikViewController

- (IBAction)showNewMovie:(id)sender {
    movieNames =@[@"Побег из шаушенка", @"Бэтмен:Начало", @"Форрест Гамп"];
    movieCovers= @[@"shawshank.jpg", @"batmanone.jpg", @"forrest.jpg"];
    movieNamesMutableCopie=[movieNames mutableCopy];
    movieCoversMutableCopie=[movieCovers mutableCopy];


    //Setting a randomindex for movie
    yourRandomIndex = arc4random_uniform(movieNamesMutableCopie.count);

    //Getting imageName and movieName at randomIndex
    NSString* movieName= movieNamesMutableCopie[yourRandomIndex];
    NSString* movieCover= movieCoversMutableCopie[yourRandomIndex];

    //Setting  ImageView image and movieName in a label from strings
    [_movieCover setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:movieCover]];
    _movieName.text = movieName;
   ;
}

- (IBAction)alreadyWatched:(id)sender {
    [movieNamesMutableCopie removeObjectAtIndex:yourRandomIndex];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSArray` is not a mutable copy. i.e. you cannot *add* or *remove* items. You should use `NSMutableArray` instead.

Your private variables (and public??) should be changed like this

```
NSArray *movieNames;
NSArray *movieCovers;
NSMutableArray *movieNamesMutableCopie;
NSMutableArray *movieCoversMutableCopie;
```